# New deep-learning tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question I just asked is just begging for it:

[Library for deep learning on images with multiple GPUs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50810/library-for-deep-learning-on-images-with-multiple-gpus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, I created the tag and added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If by deep learning the OP meant "deep" neural networks, then the OP could simply use the neural network tag. Therefore, I don't see the point in having a new deep learning tag.

Since >99% of people using the deep learning mean "deep" neural networks, I'd suggest making the  deep learning tag a synonym of neural networks, in order to avoid tag fragmentation.

Comment: That is what I meant. It sounds like a great idea to make them synonyms